# how to remove an object with as2 on a frame #

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

i'm using as2. How do i delete these snowfalkes on a certain frame? i'm creating the snowlfakes using an array on frame 40. I want to get rid of the frames around 60.

```
 var snowflake:Array;
    for (var i:Number=0;i<100;i++) {


        snowflake[i]=new Snowflake(this);
    }




import Snowflake.*;





class Snowflake {

    public var _snowflake:MovieClip;
    private var _ranSnowflake:Number;

    private var i:Number;
    private var k:Number;
    private var rad:Number;

    private static var NUM_SNOWFLAKE_TYPES:Number=7;
    private static var MOVIE_WIDTH:Number=590;
    private static var MOVIE_HEIGHT:Number=390;
    private static var FALLING_SPEED:Number=30;
    private static var WIND_SPEED:Number=5; 
    private static var ROTATION_SPEED:Number=4;

    function Snowflake(container:MovieClip) {
        this._ranSnowflake=Math.round((Math.random()*Snowflake.NUM_SNOWFLAKE_TYPES)+1);
        this._snowflake=container.attachMovie("snowflake"+this._ranSnowflake,"snowflake",container.getNextHighestDepth());
        this._snowflake._x=(Math.random()*Snowflake.MOVIE_WIDTH);
        this._snowflake._y=0;
        this._snowflake.parent=this;


        this.i=1+Math.random()*2;
        this.k=-Math.PI+Math.random()*Math.PI;
        this.rad=0;

        //giving each snowflake unique characteristics
        this._snowflake._xscale = this._snowflake._yscale=Math.random()*30;
        this._snowflake._alpha = 75+Math.random()*100;      

        this._snowflake.onEnterFrame=function() {this.parent.snowflakeEnterFrame(this._snowflake);}
        trace("SNOWFLAKE X:"+this._snowflake._x+" Y:"+this._snowflake._y);
        trace(this._currentframe);
    }

    public function snowflakeEnterFrame() {
        //putting it all together
        this.rad += (k/180)*Math.PI;
        this._snowflake._x -= Math.cos(rad);
        this._snowflake._y += i;
        if (this._snowflake._y>=Snowflake.MOVIE_HEIGHT) {
            this._snowflake._y = -Snowflake.FALLING_SPEED;
        }
        if ((this._snowflake._x>=Snowflake.MOVIE_WIDTH) || (this._snowflake._x<=0)) {
            this._snowflake._x = -Snowflake.WIND_SPEED+Math.random()*Snowflake.MOVIE_WIDTH;
            this._snowflake._y = -Snowflake.WIND_SPEED;

        }       

        this._snowflake._rotation+=Snowflake.ROTATION_SPEED;

    }

    public function vis(){
        this._snowflake.visible = false;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (should work on any frame):

```
for(var i:Number = 0; i<snowflake.length; i++){
    this.removeMovieClip(snowflake[i]._snowflake);
}
```

Loop through all the snowflake and remove them from the container.